# What would be the time complexity of Search Range problem solution DnC

Tags: algorithm, go, time-complexity

I would appreciate some help in figuring out the time complexity of the solution for [Search Range](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-first-and-last-position-of-element-in-sorted-array/) problem from leetcode which involves recursion and DnC algorithm.

I am not sure whether it is O(N) or O(NlogN) and why?

```
func searchRange(nums []int, target int) []int {
    if (len(nums) == 0) {
      return []int{-1, -1}
    }
    return helper(nums, target, 0, len(nums) - 1)
}
func helper(nums []int, target, start, end int) []int {
    res := []int {-1, -1}
    if (nums[start] > target || nums[end] < target || start > end || (start == end && nums[start] != target)) {
      return res
    }
    
    if (start == end) {
      res[0] = start
      res[1] = end
      return res
    }
    mid := (start + end) / 2
    res1 := helper(nums, target, start, mid)
    res2 := helper(nums, target, mid + 1, end)
    if (res1[0] == -1) {
      return res2
    }
    if (res2[0] == -1) {
      return res1
    }
    res[0] = res1[0]
    res[1] = res2[1]
    return res
}
```

Comment: To analyze time complexity, write down your [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation). Here each call to helper() calls helper() twice, but with n/2 numbers to inspect. Each function call *may* return early in some cases: which ones?

Comment: @torek. Is it 2^logN which is O(N) ?

Comment: It would be without the early returns, yes. But suppose every early-return always returns, then how many recursive calls do you make? (This one's obvious: none at all, since the initial call itself does the early return.) So now it's O(1). So we know the worst case is O(n) and the best case is O(1). That makes it a little tricky to do the expected average case...

Comment: Note that we're about to make a really big assumption (or assertion): `nums` is assumed to be (or asserted to be) *sorted*, so that nums[0] < nums[1], nums[1] < nums[2], etc. What can you now say about the conditions under which the short-circuit early return occurs?